# Event-driven architecture - why is there no tool for this?

Tags: microservices, event-driven, event-driven-design

For a new application I am developing I am interested in creating a microservice that allows for events to be created (for example: New order placed) and other microservices to react to these events (for example the payment system listens to the New order event and processes the payment).

Is there any open source project that I can use to do this in a reliable way?

Comment: Eventuate is open source, see: `https://github.com/eventuate-local/eventuate-local`

Answer (score 1):

Try [geteventstore](https://geteventstore.com/) or [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) and read  [this stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708489/using-kafka-as-a-cqrs-eventstore-good-idea)