# Eventsourcing in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, event-sourcing

Using Kafka as an event store works fine, its easy to just set message retention to unlimited.

But I've seen some reports on Kafka being used for event sourcing also.
And here is where I get confused on how that is possible.
As an event store, I can just shove my messages in there. and consume or replay as needed.

But for event sourcing, you most likely want to read the events for a given entity/aggregate ID.
You could of course use partitions, but that seems like abusing the concept and it would be hard to actually add new entities as the partition count is more on the static side, even if you can change it.
Are there any sane solution to this out there?
The Apache Kafka docs themselves only mention Event Sourcing briefly.

Comment: There is discussion around the use of Kafka as an event store here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708489/using-kafka-as-a-cqrs-eventstore-good-idea. They've also got Kafka Streams which might be a better abstraction for this?

Comment: Martin Kleppmann has a [good talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avi-TZI9t2I&t=3s) about using Kafka in an event-driven architecture, if that can help. My take on it is that they were originally 2 quite different approaches and can take some work and concessions to be hybridized

Comment: Also more here https://www.confluent.io/blog/event-sourcing-cqrs-stream-processing-apache-kafka-whats-connection/

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment on the other question:

> Thanks for the effort here, the answer is pretty off topic though. "Is it what you want to express really?" No. The question is not about DDD nor CQRS. I'm well familiar with those. I'm asking how or if I can use Kafka for eventsouring. Lets say I have 10 million entities, I might not want to have them all loaded in memory across servers at once. Can I load the data for a single aggregate using Kafka w/o replaying everything ?

The answer is yes: you can use [Kafka Streams](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html) to process the events. Your streams logic generates aggregates and stores them in local state stores (RocksDB), so that the resulting aggregates don't need to be in memory and can be accessed without replaying all the events. You can access these aggregates with the [Interactive Queries API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#interactive-queries). It's quite nice! At this time, writing event processing logic that's replayable is [easier said than done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482974/741970), but not impossible by any means.

Answer (score -3):

I think Apache Kafka is the best solution to store events for Event Sourcing. The concept of Event Sourcing is very close and usually works together with a concept/practice named CQRS by Greg Young which I suggest you to research.

The term **repository** I am using in this answer is a repository in terms of Domain Driven Design as in Eric Evans book.

I think I know what is a reason of the confusion you have.

> But for event sourcing, you most likely want to read the events for a given entity/aggregate ID.

<strike>The above of your question is in my opinion true.  But</strike> I think that you wanted to express something different. You wanted to express something like this:

> In event sourcing, when repository is asked to retrieve an object from its data source, the repository must retrieve all events that constitutes particular entity in every request to the repository. Then these events must be replayed to build up the object.

<strike>Is it what you want to express really? Because</strike> The sentence above is in my opinion **false**.

**You do not need to rebuild an object every time you retrieve it.**

In other words, you don't need to replay all the events that constitutes the object every time you retrieve the object from repository. You can play events on the object and store current version of the object in a different way, e.g. in cache or even better, both in cache and in kafka.

So let's talk an example. Let's say we have a track/lorry that is loaded and unloaded.

The main stream of the events will be **operations** - this will be 1st kafka topic in our app. This will be our *source of truth* as Jay Kreps usually says it his papers.

These are the events:

- track 1 is loaded with pigs
- track 2 is loaded with pigs
- track 2 is unloaded from pigs
- track 2 is loaded with sand
- track 1 is unloaded from pigs
- track 1 is loaded with flowers

The final result is that track 1 is filled with flowers and track 2 is filled with sand.

What you do is you read the events from this topic and populate your 2nd topic: **trackUpdated**. The events you stream into **trackUpdated** topic are following:

- track 1: pigs
- track 2: pigs
- track 2: nothing
- track 2: sand
- track 1: nothing
- track 1: flowers

At the same time, with every message consumed, you update current version of the truck in cache e.g. memcached. So memcache will be a direct source which repository use to retrive track object.

What is more you make the **trackUpdated** topic a *compacted* topic.

Read about compacted topics in Apache Kafka official docs. There is lot of interesing materials about it on Confluent blog and Linkedin Engineering blog (before Confluent company was started).

So because of the fact that **trackUpdated** is compated Kafka makes it look like this after some time:

- track 2: sand
- track 1: flowers

Kafka will do this if you use track ID as a key for all messages - read in the docs what message "keys" are. So you end up with 1 message for every track. If you find bug in your app you can replay **operations** topic to populate your cache and **trackUpdated** topic again. If your cache goes down you can use **trackUpdated** topic to populate your cache.

What do you think? Votes and comments highly welcomed.

### Update:

(1) After some thoughts I have changed my mind that a quote of you is true. I find it false now. So I do **not(( think that *for event sourcing, you most likely want to read the events for a given entity/aggregate ID*.

When you find a bug in your code you want to replay all the events for all objects. It does not matter if there are 2 entities as in my simple example or there is 10M entities.

**Event sourcing is not about retrieving all the events for particular entity. Event sourcing is about that you have your audit log of all events and you are able to replay them to rebuild your entities. You don't need to be able to rebuild single particular entity**.

(2) Strongly advice to get familiar with some blog posts of Confluent and LinkedIn engineering blogs. The below was very interesing for me:

https://www.confluent.io/blog/making-sense-of-stream-processing/

https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying

Official Kafka Docs is a must too.

Comment: Thanks for the effort here, the answer is pretty off topic though.
"Is it what you want to express really?"
No.
The question is not about DDD nor CQRS. I'm well familiar with those.
I'm asking how or if I can use Kafka for eventsouring.
Lets say I have 10 million entities, I might not want to have them all loaded in memory across servers at once.
Can I load the data for a single aggregate using Kafka w/o replaying everything ?

Comment: @RogerAlsing What Kafka is giving you in terms of event sourcing is the ability to very easily replay all the events every time you need it. To answer your specific question: no, you can not load the data for a single aggregate w/o replaying everything. What my answer was trying to convince you to is to ask yourself if you really want/need to do this. I think you don't. You don't need to have them all loaded in memory too. It might be some SQL, elastic, mongo etc. Compacted topics helps here a lot too. I have updated my answer a bit, please check the ending! Sorry for an offtopic! :) Cheers!

Comment: @miglanc you're suggesting always maintaining a current snapshot of state for each entity in both an external data store and in a compacted Kafka topic as well as the original events in another Kafka topic? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @RogerAlsing no I don't think so due to the limit on topics. The Kafka version of event sourcing seems to be in terms of a topic-per-category where all events for all entities of a given type would go.

Comment: @tomliversidge (1) Yes, I am suggesting to keep all original events somewhere. It's a must. It's all ES is about: an audit log + ability to replay. It doesn't have to be Kafka but I think it's the best data store for it. (2) Yes, I am suggesting to maintain current snapshot of a state for each entity in at least one data store that is best for your use case. It might be Kafka + memcached. It might be SQL or ElasticSearch only. It depends on your use case. The point is not to compute all the events each time you want to retrieve an entity. See Martin Fowler video "Event sourcing". And you?

Comment: Snapshots have traditionally been used when performance of replaying many events becomes an issue. Of course you need to keep the original events, but it seems like your suggestion is the equivalent of how view models are normally built (the Q in CQRS), rather than aggregates / entities. I think the DDD community and the Kafka community have different ways of looking at event sourcing - the approach I'm used to is what @RogerAlsing was asking if Kafka supported

Comment: I think that the Kafka way of forcing the use of snapshots is workable - each Kafka partition for the aggregate event stream needs to have a single thread handling commands, to avoid any issues with consistency. That thread can also cache recent aggregate snapshots in memory, but fetch stale ones from the snapshots db, which is updated after each event is written of course. The snapshots db can be a fast object store of some kind (just a key-value store) - it can be rebuilt if necessary. Crash recovery is quite simple - just replay from where the snapshots db has got to.