# Axon or Kafka to support CQRS/ES

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

Consider the simple use case in which I want to store product ratings as events in an event store.

I could use two different approaches:

1. Using **Axon**: A Rating aggregate is responsible for handling the CreateRatingCommand and sending the RatingCreatedEvent. Sending the event would case the Rating to be stored in the event store. Other event handlers have the possibility to replay the event stream when connecting to the Axon server instance and doing whatever needed with the ratings. In this case, the event handler will be used as a stream processor.
2. Using **Kafka**: A KafkaProducer will be used to store a Rating POJO (after proper serialization) in a Kafka topic. Setting the topic's retention time to indefinite would cause no events to get lost in time. Kafka Streams would in this case be used to do the actual rating processing logic.

Some architectural questions appear to me for both approaches:

When using **Axon**:

1. Is there any added value to use Axon (or similar solutions) if there is no real state to be maintained or altered within the aggregate? The aggregate just serves as a "dumb" placeholder for the data, but does not provide any state changing logic.
2. How does Axon handle multiple event handlers of the same event type? Will they all handle the same event (same aggregate id) in parallel, or is the same event only handled once by one of the handlers?
3. Are events stored in the Axon event store kept until the end of time?

When using **Kafka**:

1. Kafka stores events/messages with the same key in the same partition. How does one select the best value for a key in the use case of user-product ratings? UserId, ProductId or a separate topic for both and publish each event in both topics.
2. Would it be wise to use a separate topic for each user and each product resulting in a massive amount of topics on the cluster? (Approximately <5k products and >10k users).

I don't know if SO is the preferred forum for this kind of questions... I was just wondering what you (would) recommend in this particular use case as the best practise. Looking forward to your feedback and feel free to point out other points of thought I missed in the previous questions.

**EDIT@12/11/2020** : I just found a [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708489/using-kafka-as-a-cqrs-eventstore-good-idea) containing useful information related to my question.

Comment: SO really might not be the best platform to discuss this, it will be easily closed as "opinion based" or "too broad" ... this is the axon forum https://discuss.axoniq.io.  I would try this there, they are not just selling their product there.

Comment: I agree! Thanks for pointing me to the appropriate forum. Should I remove this post?

Comment: No need to remove it. Especially now that it has an answer with valuable information in it. Chances are it will be closed as "opinion based" so I'd recommend to continue any further discussion at https://discuss.axoniq.io/t/axon-or-kafka-to-support-cqrs-es/2889 Seems like everyone participating here so far is available there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jan Galinski already puts it, this hasn't got a fool proof answer to it really. This is worth a broader discussion on for example indeed [AxonIQ's Discuss forum](https://discuss.axoniq.io/). Regardless, there are some questions in here I can definitely give an answer to, so let's get to it:

1. **Axon Question 1** - Axon Framework is as you've noticed used a lot for DDD centric applications. Nothing however forces you to base yourself on that notion at all. You can strip the framework from Event Sourcing specifics, as well as modelling specifics entirely and purely go for the messaging idea of distinct commands, events and queries. It has been a conscious decision to segregate Axon Framework version 3 into these sub-part when version 4 (current) was released actually. Next to that, I think there is great value in not just basing yourself on event messages. Using distinct commands and queries only further decouples your components, making for a far richer and easier to extend application landscape.
2. **Axon Question 2** - This depends on *where* the `@EventHandler` annotated methods are located actually. If they're in the same class only one will be invoked. If they're positioned into distinct classes, then both will receive the same event. Furthermore if they're segregated between distinct classes, it is important to note Axon uses an Event Processor as the technical solution to invoking your event handlers. If distinct classes are grouped under the same Event Processor, you can impose a certain ordering which handler is invoked first. Next to this if the event handling should occur in parallel, you will have to configure a so called `TrackingEventProcessor` (the default in Axon Framework), as it allows configuration of several threads to handle events concurrently. Well, to conclude this section, everything you're asking in question two is an option, neither a necessity. Just a matter of configuration really. Might be worth checking up on [this](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors) documentation page of Axon Framework on the matter.
3. **Axon Question 3** - As Axon Server serves the purpose of an Event Store, there is no retention period at all. So yes, they're by default kept until the end of time. There is nothing stopping your from dropping the events though, if you feel there's no value in storing the events to for example base all your models on (as you'd do when using Event Sourcing).

It's the Kafka question I'm personally less familiar with (figures as a contributor to Axon Framework I guess). I can give you my two cents on the matter here too though, although I'd recommend a second opinion here:

1. **Kafka Question 1** - From my personal feeling of what such an application would require, I'd assume you'd want to be able to retrieve all data for a given product as efficient as possible. I'd wager it's important that all events are in the same partition to make this process as efficient as possible, is it wouldn't require any merging afterwards. With this in mind, I'd think using the `ProductId` will make most sense.
2. **Kafka Question 2** - If you are anticipating only 5_000 products and 10_000 users, I'd guess it should be doable to have separate topics for these. *Opinion incoming* - It is here though were I personally feel that Kafka's intent to provide you direct power to decide on when to use topics over complicates from what you'd actually try to achieve, which business functionality. Giving the power to segregate streams feels more like an after thought from the perspective of application development. As soon as you'd require an enterprise grade/efficient message bus, that's when this option really shines I think, as then you can optimize for bulk.

Hoping all this helps you further @KDW!